# change hostname for continuous integration testing

Tags: python, nose

I have some functionality that only runs in specific physical locations and it is known by the hostname.  This is produced in a cython module that calls socket.gethostname().

Is there anyway to make a test using socket.gethostname() have different data from the host the test is running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`mock` module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html):

```
import mock
import socket

with mock.patch("socket.gethostname", return_value="completely fake"):
    print socket.gethostname()
```

Thsi prints `completely fake` on `stdout`.

`mock` is bundled with Python 3.3 and over (as `unittest.mock`) and is available as a backport for Python 2.6.x and up. The above code runs as-is with Python 2.7.x.

Comment: Perfect.  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is very convenient to test host-dependent code.